# TiBlob getBytes returning length of 0 on Android

Tags: android, titanium

Application type: mobile
Titanium SDK: 3.3.0
Platform: Android
Device: Motorola Moto X (4.4.2)
Host OS: Mac OS X Mavericks

I'm having an issue when trying to use the getBytes() method of the TiBlob object in an Android Titanium module I'm building. My function takes in a TiBlob as such

```
public void setImage(TiBlob blob) {
    ...
    byte[] byteArray = blob.getBytes();
    ...
}
```

When I call the function in javascript, I do it as such:

```
Ti.API.info("Calling toImage function");
var image_blob = image.toImage();
Ti.API.info("Setting image from blob");
image_module.image = image_blob;
```

When the setImage function is called, I get this error:

```
[DEBUG] ImageblurModule: (KrollRuntimeThread) [4502,4502] Converting blob to byte array
[DEBUG] ImageblurModule: (KrollRuntimeThread) [2,4504] {height=510, cropRect={x=0, width=720, height=510}, media=[object TiBlob], y=0, mimeType=image/png, x=0, width=720}
[WARN]  W/System.err: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=786812398
[WARN]  W/System.err:   at java.util.LinkedHashMap.get(LinkedHashMap.java:253)
[WARN]  W/System.err:   at com.globesherpa.imageblur.ImageblurModule.setImage(ImageblurModule.java:78)
[WARN]  W/System.err:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Object.nativeFireEvent(Native Method)
[WARN]  W/System.err:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Object.fireEvent(V8Object.java:64)
[WARN]  W/System.err:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.doFireEvent(KrollProxy.java:884)
[WARN]  W/System.err:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.handleMessage(KrollProxy.java:1107)
[WARN]  W/System.err:   at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleMessage(TiViewProxy.java:347)
[WARN]  W/System.err:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
[WARN]  W/System.err:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
[WARN]  W/System.err:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime$KrollRuntimeThread.run(KrollRuntime.java:112)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Even though there is no documentation on this, in Android you have to use blob.media when you pass the blob from JavaScript. For example, if you're using the .toImage() function, it must be like this:

```
var imageBlob = win.toImage().media;

imageModule.image = imageBlob;
```

Hope this helps others on their journey through Titanium.